# Authetiction save and callback

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, authentication, tkinter

I think my save and read function are wrong.The structure way also wrong i i guess.Already check in the internet but still not working to write and read back in text file. Is it the correct way to make the authentcation?Can somebody give any other example or correct what im wrong at.These is my code

```
 import Tkinter 
    WindowBox = Tkinter.Tk()
    WindowBox.geometry("250x200")
    WindowBox.title("Welcome to E-UPSR")

    getusername1 = Tkinter.StringVar()
    getpassword1 = Tkinter.StringVar()
    getusername2 = Tkinter.StringVar()
    getpassword2 = Tkinter.StringVar()

    LabelName = Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Username:")
    LabelName.pack()
    TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox, textvariable= getusername1)
    TxtBoxName.pack()

    LabelName = Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Password:")
    LabelName.pack()
    TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox, textvariable= getpassword1)
    TxtBoxName.pack()

    student=[]


    def read():
        getusername1 = Tkinter.StringVar()
        getpassword1 = Tkinter.StringVar()
        if len(getusername1.get() and getpassword1())== 0:
                labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(WindowBox, text="Invalid").pack()
        else:
            addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
            addstudent.read("Username:" + getusername1.get())
            addstudent.read("Password: " + getpassword1.get())
            addstudent.close ()
            WindowBox.withdraw()
            MenuBox.deiconify()   
        return

    def register():
        WindowBox.withdraw()
        RegBox.deiconify()
        return

    RegBox = Tkinter.Tk()
    RegBox.geometry("250x200")
    RegBox.title("register")

    LabelName = Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Username:")
    LabelName.pack()
    TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getusername2)
    TxtBoxName.pack()
    LabelName = Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Password:")
    LabelName.pack()
    TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getpassword2)
    TxtBoxName.pack()
    RegBox.withdraw()

    def back():
        RegBox.withdraw()
        WindowBox.deiconify()
        return    


    def save():
        while True:
            getusername2 = Tkinter.StringVar()
            getpassword2 = Tkinter.StringVar()
            if len(getusername2.get() and getpassword2())== 0:
                labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(RegBox, text="Please key-in").pack()
            else:
                addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
                addstudent.write('Username:' + getusername2.get())
                addstudent.write('Password:' + getpassword2.get())
                labelShowName=Tkinter.Label(RegBox, text="Done").pack()
        len(getusername2.get() and getpassword2.get())!= 0
        return

    MenuBox = Tkinter.Tk()
    MenuBox.geometry("250x200")
    MenuBox.title("MainMenu")
    MenuBox.withdraw()

    BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back).pack()   
    BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Enter", command=save).pack()
    BtnName = Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Register", command=register).pack()
    BtnName = Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Proceed", command=read).pack()


    WindowBox.mainloop()
```

Comment: you open file in write mode "w" and you try to `read()` - don't you get error message ?

Comment: first you create global `getusername1` and use in `Entry` but later you create local `getusername1` in function `read()` - this way you can't get value from `Entry`. Don't create local variable.

Comment: `getpassword1` is not function. You can't use with `()` - `getpassword1()`. It has to be `getpassword1.get()`.

Comment: `len(getusername2.get() and getpassword2())== 0` doesn't do what you expect . It has to be `len(getusername2.get()) == 0  or len(getpassword2.get()) ==  0`

Comment: `while True` in function `save()` freezes all program - you have to use `break` to leave this loop - or `return` to leave this function.

Comment: while true function save() freeze al program? can you give some example?i appreciate it

Comment: the save  function not works